# Jquery $ mark escape

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
$("#Camera").webcam({
            width: 320,
            height: 240,
            mode: "save",
            swffile: "@Url.Content("~/Content/jQueryWebcam/jscam.swf")",
             onTick: function () { },
             onSave: function () {
             },
             onCapture: function () {

                 webcam.save("@Url.Content("~/StudentRSRegistration/Capture?StudentIDD="+$("#StudentID").val())");
             },
            debug: function () { },
            onLoad: function () { }
        });
```

code above displays an error near $("#StudentID").val() dollar sign. How to escape his character?

Comment: Why dont you keep it in a variable and then pass. 
var id = $("#StudentId").val();

Comment: try escaping " sign instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is not with the dollar symbol - it's that you're trying to mix server-side and client-side code, which is impossible in the manner you're using. You need to restructure the logic, like this:

```
webcam.save('@Url.Content("~/StudentRSRegistration/Capture?StudentIDD=")' + $("#StudentID").val());
```